# JSON schema reference key value as the type of the field

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have the following schema:

```
    schema: {
      type: 'array',
      items: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          type: {
            enum: ['string', 'number', 'boolean']
          },
          value: {
            type: ??,
          }
        }
      }

    }
```

How can I set the `type` of `value` based on the `enum` of the `type` property? For example:

```
{
  "type": "string",
  "value": 1 // this shouldn't be valid
}

{
  "type": "number",
  "value": 1 // this is fine
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: From the answer: "You cannot extract the value of data from your JSON instance to use in your JSON Schema."